# Fixing External Library Python

Tags: python, django

I've been using an external Library for my Django project Called djutils. But since it has been discontinued a lot of outdated stuff were there. Because of it, I've to fix a couple of mistakes in multiple files and now I need to export it to my production application, but I don't to simply write all the modifications again.

How could I do that? I just need to copy it from :

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/djutils
```

And overwrite at my production application virtual env? There are any other easy ways to do that?

Cheers,

Pedro Gabriel.

Comment: djutils is an app so if you copy it to your project folder as an app then also it would work

Comment: You can "vendor" that module into a local folder and distribute it with your app.  If you prefer to manage this as a separate module, you could store the altered library in a private PyPi server like Gemfury and then install the modified library using a standard `pip install` command.

Answer (score 0):

1. you can create github repo with your current code and use pip install `git+https://github.com/blahblah@commit#egg=djutils`
2. you can just copy the file and include them under your project (just copy the directory to the path where all your apps are)